# Resizing local containers in const method through base class with template specialisations

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constants, specialization

I want to create instances of a class and, depending on the type, provide a resize functionality, which is only applicable to containers that provide such functionality (for simplicity, lets assume its just a vector). The resizing is done in a base class as I have several classes that have a common base but all requiring the same functionality.

The following code demonstrates the current problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class base {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    void resize(T &var, T &resizer) {
      var.resize(resizer.size());
      std::cout << "resized a vector" << std::endl;
    }

    void resize(double &var, double &resizer) {
      std::cout << "just a double, no resizing done" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class child1 : public base {
  public:
    void doOperation() const {
      T a, b;
      // assume here that b has actually a different size from a
      this->resize(a, b);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class child2 : public base {
  public:
    void wildlyDifferentOperation() const {
      T c, d;
      // assume here that d has actually a different size from c
      this->resize(c, d);
    }
};

int main() {
  child1<std::vector<double>> obj1;
  obj1.doOperation();

  child2<std::vector<int>> obj2;
  obj2.wildlyDifferentOperation();

  child1<double> obj3;
  obj3.doOperation();
  return 0;
}
```

As shown here, I used template specializations to catch types that can not be resized (and I know that it will always be a double) and I use a templated version for the containers that can be resized, as I don't know ahead which types I actually need (i.e. it could be `std::vector<int>`, `std::vector<double>` etc...).

Of course, if I remove `const` from the `doOperation()` method then the code works as expected but with the const I get an error saying `error: passing ‘const child1<std::vector<double> >’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]` which is not surprising (and I get a similar message for child2 and `wildlyDifferentOperation()`).

My question now is how can I use the code above to make it work? I though I could maybe `const_cast` the arguments in `this->resize` or use `mutable` and then declare `T a` as class member variables to no avail.
Any suggestions are welcome but I would like the following to remain the same:

1. `void doOperation()` and `wildlyDifferentOperation()` should remain `const`
2. I want to be able to create local variables as `T a` inside `doOperation()` and `wildlyDifferentOperation()` and pass those to a separate method where they get resized if they are a container. To make things simpler, I know that I will either get a `double` or a container, but I don't want to impose any restriction on the template arguments of the container (i.e. accept std::vector, std::vector and so forth)
3. I need to be able to use the same functionality to resize my containers from other child classes that derive from the base class.

If there is a cleaner solution not requiring template specializations that would also be acceptable. It should, however, work with a C++14 conform compiler.

Comment: Why can't you declare `resize` as a const method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `base::resize` either `static` or `const`. Without knowing the semantics of what you're going for here, I would guess `const`.